# jQuery Is not a number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that sum values. How can I do for when I type something that is not a number, keep the result at 0?

Some code:

```
$(document).on('keyup','input',newSum);
function newSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    var total = 0;

    $(thisRow).find("td:not(.total) input").each(function () {
        sum += parseInt(this.value);
    });

     // Insertamos el color de la suma de cada fila.
     if((sum % 2 == 0)) {$(thisRow).find('.total').animate( { backgroundColor: 'green' }, 1000);}
     else{$(thisRow).find('.total').animate( { backgroundColor: 'red' }, 1000);}

    $(thisRow).find(".total").html(sum);
    $('.total').each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).html());
    });

}
```

[FULL CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/2JVP5/)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should check isNumeric =>  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [short circuit boolean evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): `sum += +this.value || 0;`

The `+` tries to box the value to a `Number`, if that fails use value `0`

Comment: Why `null` instead of `0`?

Comment: @Curt: typo, sorry. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum+= isNaN(Number(this.value))?0:Number(this.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code to stop the keypress for non numeric numbers

[Code Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2JVP5/4/)

Js Code :

```
function checkAlphbet(event) {
  var code = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
  var currentKey = alphabetKeyRestriction(code, true);
  if (!currentKey) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

}
```